# How to set firebase rules so that cloud firestore can only be accessed from web-app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am running a simple single page web app via firebase with which you can request information from cloud firestore.

Those are my security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read ;
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem** With these rules, anyone who knows the link of my database can of course access the databse.

**Question** Is there any way to change these rules, so that you can only access the database through my web-app (with anonymous login)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible at all, even with security rules.  You can control *who* can access *what* with security rules, but it's not possible to control *where* they're coming from, or the context of the request.